# Unable to use pygame.PixelArray properly

Tags: pygame

I'm trying to make a per-pixel 2D lighting system, but I keep getting a weird error. Here's my code with explanations along the way:

```
import pygame, sys, math

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

screen_width = 640
screen_height = 480

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Light sources")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

These are the regular setup lines for any pygame game

```
darkness = pygame.image.load("grafiikka/pimeys.png")
darkness.set_alpha(254)

lights_list = [] ### For controlling all light sources at a time
```

Loading in a one-colored darkness image. This will be blit on top of everything else to make it dark. I would then simulate light by changing the alpha value of the darkness in the light area.

```
class lightsource: ### The parameters for a light
    def ___init___(self, loc, ang, direction, radius):
        self.loc = loc
        self.ang = ang
        self.dir = direction
        self.radius = radius
```

I make the lightsource class

```
def LightDraw(): ### Drawing the lights, pixel per pixel
    for v in lights_list:
        for i in range (int((v.dir - v.ang/2)), int((v.dir + v.ang/2))):
            for l in range (0, v.radius):
                if int(i) < 90 and int(i) >= 0:
                    x = (v.loc[0]) + int(-l * math.cos(math.radians(i)))
                    y = (v.loc[1]) + int(-l * math.sin(math.radians(i)))
                elif i < 180 and i >= 90:
                    x = (v.loc[0]) + int(l * math.cos(math.pi - math.radians(i)))
                    y = (v.loc[1]) + int(-l * math.sin(math.pi - math.radians(i)))
                elif i < 270 and i >= 180:
                    x = (v.loc[0]) + int(l * math.sin(1.5 * math.pi - math.radians(i)))
                    y = (v.loc[1]) + int(l * math.cos(1.5 * math.pi - math.radians(i)))
                elif i < 360 and i >= 270:
                    x = (v.loc[0]) + int(-l * math.cos(2 * math.pi - math.radians(i)))
                    y = (v.loc[1]) + int(l * math.sin(2 * math.pi - math.radians(i)))
                alpha = int(254 * (l / v.radius))
                print(int(254 * (l / v.radius)))
                pygame.TempPimeys[x, y] = pygame.Color.a(alpha) ### THIS CAUSES ERROR

    return TempPimeys.make_surface()

### Adding a test light source at (300, 200) on screen    
testValo = lightsource()
testValo.___init___((300,200), 360, 90, 100)
lights_list.append(testValo)
```

**The error is in the function**, namely in the line where I'm actually changing the alpha value. I don't understand what the heck is causing the error.

```
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    myOtherImage_rect.topleft = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    screen.fill(white)
    TempPimeys = pygame.PixelArray(pimeys)
    hämärä = LightDraw()
    screen.unlock()
    screen.blit(hämärä, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

And the general loop.

The error I'm getting is: TypeError: 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable

Comment: Can you tell me the line number the error gives, and give the entire code with no breaks?

Answer (score 0):

```
pygame.TempPimeys[x, y] = pyame.Color.a(alpha) ### THIS CAUSES ERROR

# same as
>>> pygame.Color.a(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable
```

You're calling `a` as a class method `pygame.Color.a()` when it expects to be an instance. Ex:

```
>>> pygame.Color('red')
(255, 0, 0, 255)
>>> c = pygame.Color('red')
>>> c.a
255
>>> c.a = 20
```

If the reason is you only want to modify **alpha** and not **RGB**, then you can use [pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I believe that is the right way to go. However, using surfarray requires numpy, and I am unable to get IT working. Any installer I try to run just crashes or after installing I cannot import it.

Comment: Using your method, I got this code:

TempPimeys = pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(pimeys)
and it causes an error in numpy: ValueError: unsupported colormasks for alpha reference array

Is there something wrong with my image? It's a normal .png format, there shouldn't be any problems with that.

Comment: Can you paste the full code on paste bin so I can try running it?  To install numpy make sure you match the python version and the same 32/64bit version you used to install python. I use 32 to make it easier to install packages, even though the OS is 64bit.

Comment: My python and numpy are both 32bit, so that shouldn't be the case. What do you mean by pastebin? My code is all in the first post just with some explanations in between the segments